# Optimize sysem utilization Java Application

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, utilization

Short about the program:

It's my first program and is therefore not best and most effectively programmed path but it works and does the job. The program diehnt as Design Management. It manages about 3000 designs. It can be sorted by each group for each group are then generated in a scrollPane container. There each design is specific number displayed a small preview with 20-30 kb and even a style name. These designs dan can still be filtered in more detail and dan be printed or sent via e-mail.

In the appendix a few screenshots of the application so you do including about anything imaginable.
The program has been programmed using XDEV.

Problem # 1:

It will appear in the scrollPane only about 200 designs to more must be seen to be turned over. Say the scrollPane once emptied and refilled with the dan designs. The problem is that it takes to load the images for too long. The sql query and generation of container in which the designs are displayed takes about 500ms. But until the images are loaded, it takes about 5 seconds. The pictures are on an external server and downloaded over the network, there is a dedicated line and on the Internet speed it can not lie.

What's the fastest way to load images into the program and therefore the show is fully charged in about 1-2 seconds?

Problem # 2:

The program takes too much system performance. If I press the button of the SQL query, which starts generation of container and loading the images increases system utilization briefly to 90-100%. For a normal PC is not necessarily a problem but the program is running on a terminal server and there is a big problem when the system increases capacity utilization. As I mentioned have only started with the program and do not know myself why I still look good even everything up out in a single thread, ie the main thread in the the window itself is generated.

How can I eliminate the system performance in a search only slightly increases ie below 10%? Would it help if I gave the loading of the images and the SQL query in a separate thread? Or how can I solve this best?

Comment: *"The program diehnt as Design Management"* What?

Comment: I think this is too broad. Maybe you could split into multiple questions (one issue, one question)

Comment: sry i dont read it i only translated it with google translate and didnt have the time to read it. Ok i will ask only 1 question with one issue.